# CURL-ing a package to gitlab package registry fails with {"error":"package_version is invalid"}

Tags: cmake, gitlab, package, gitlab-ci

My gitlab CI pipeline has an "upload" stage which issues two curl calls that upload my binaries to a gitlab package. Here's my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
stages:
  - build
  - upload
  - release

variables:
    PACKAGE_REGISTRY_URL: "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/generic/binaries/${CI_COMMIT_TAG}"
    BINARY_NAME: "controller.bin"

build-job:
  image: espressif/idf:release-v5.1
  stage: build
  script:
    - bash build-ci.sh
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 30 days
    paths:
      - build01/    #adapt name to build folders in build-ci.sh
      - build02/    #adapt name to build folders in build-ci.sh

upload-job:             # Uploads binaries as packages
  stage: upload
  image: curlimages/curl:latest
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
  script:
    - |
      curl --header "JOB-TOKEN: ${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" --upload-file build01/${BINARY_NAME} "${PACKAGE_REGISTRY_URL}/01-${BINARY_NAME}"
    - |
      curl --header "JOB-TOKEN: ${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" --upload-file build02/${BINARY_NAME} "${PACKAGE_REGISTRY_URL}/02-${BINARY_NAME}"

release-job:
  stage: release
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
  script:
    - echo "running release-job"
  release:                               # See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#release for available properties
    tag_name: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'
    description: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'
    ref: '$CI_COMMIT_SHA'
    assets:
        links:
            - name: 01-${BINARY_NAME}
              url: ${PACKAGE_REGISTRY_URL}/01-${BINARY_NAME}
            - name: 02-${BINARY_NAME}
              url: ${PACKAGE_REGISTRY_URL}/02-${BINARY_NAME}
```

Every stage completes successfully, however, the second stage appears to fail the upload via curl. This is the output:

```
$ curl --header "JOB-TOKEN: ${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" --upload-file build01/${BINARY_NAME} "${PACKAGE_REGISTRY_URL}/01-${BINARY_NAME}"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1028k  100    38  100 1028k    128  3474k --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 3485k{"error":"package_version is invalid"}
$ curl --header "JOB-TOKEN: ${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" --upload-file build02/${BINARY_NAME} "${PACKAGE_REGISTRY_URL}/02-${BINARY_NAME}"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1028k  100    38  100 1028k    134  3643k --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 3633k
{"error":"package_version is invalid"}
```

So the API responds with {"error":"package_version is invalid"} but I don't even know where the package version is specified? The artifacts are just CMake build directories. What's not right here?